# java - coordinates into an array

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to get these rectangles coordinates into an array(using a loop), but I can't get them right. The values in the array in default are "false". For example if the coordinates are 0, 24 blockCoords[0][1] shoud be "true". Sorry for my English, I'm not a native speaker :P

```
boolean[ ][ ] blockCoords = new boolean[20][10];//the array

//added the code to create the array
  private void createArray() {
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
             for(int j=0;j<10;j++) {
                  blockCoords[i][j]=false;
          }
      }
  }
//b is the block
int y1 = b.getY();//get the coordinates of the top of a block
int y2 = b.getHeight();//the height of a block
int x1 = b.getX();
int x2 = b.getWidth();
int numHorizontal = 10-((240-x2)/24);//calculates how many blocks there are - 24 is the width and the height of a block - 240/480 are the dimensions
int numVertical = 20-((480-y2)/24);
int col=10-((240-x1)/24);//in which column does the block's coordinates start in
int row=((480-y1)/24)-1;// same for the row
```

Comment: So a rectangle `b` may cover multiple blocks in `blockCoords`, and you want all covered blocks to be set to `true`?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm going for

Answer (score 0):

You never assign any value to the array blockCoords so it could never assume any other value than false. I suspect you meant to use the x and y coordinates to assign a value to the array.

Comment: I assigned the values in a method I didn't bother to post. Here it is:    private void createArray() {
       for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
           for(int j=0;j<10;j++) {
               blockCoords[i][j]=false;
           }
       }
   }

Comment: Ok, but where do you assign it to true? I think @Elias has the soulution for you

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question:

```
for(int i = row; i < numVertical; i++){
    for(int j = col; j < numHorizontal; j++){
        blockCoords[i][j] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't work... in your example the "coordinates" are [0,0][1,0][0,2][1,2] when they should be [0,0][0,1][0,2][0,3]

Comment: Whoops, I run this method twice for two blocks at a time so my answer should be "in your example the coordinates are [0,0][1,0] when they should be [0,0][0,1]"

Comment: The inner `for` runs completely for each loop of the outer `for`. So `j` is incremented ultil `numHorizontal` before `i` to be incremented. Dude, you need to explain better your problem.